# Copy text from multiple cells from one sheet and paste to another

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have 2 different tabs in my excel file.
Sheet 1 will have all the master content.
Sheet 2 will be a copy of Sheet 1.
Please see the picture attach of the content for Sheet 1.
I would like Sheet 2 to copy the information from the cells with text and copy over to Sheet 2.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3oSk.jpg)

Update:

Please see attachments for error window and code:

```
   Sub Copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:I95").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
End Sub
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eo73.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NqxU.jpg)

Comment: From the linked thread: "You only get that error for one reason: the name your provided does not exist in the collection!"

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty basic stuff. Try:

I have edited for you due to comments below. Put this in your worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:D10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" error message appeared. I put the code into the worksheet code module instead of the individual module. Would anything have to change?

Comment: @DM24 - why would you put this in a sheet code module?

Comment: @BigBen I would like the copying over to happen without me running a macro manually, but rather copy over simultaneously. Is that a bad approach?

Comment: @BigBen If I do it in an individual module, i get subscript out of range error.

Comment: Then you either have no sheet named *Sheet1* or no sheet named *Sheet2* in the active workbook, or are missing both.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you need to do, do you want to copy sheet 1 to sheet 2 as soon as you click on(activate) sheet 1? If so then in your worksheet module change the declaration to "activate". Also if your getting a "Subscript out of range" that's usually because the sheet your trying to copy does not currently exist, i'm guessing that's sheet 2, so you would need to add sheet 2. Try adding Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2" at the beginning of your worksheet module.

Comment: @steveP I do have Sheet2 created. I have updated the original post with the error and content of the module.